# Remove sublist from a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 lists: `list1` and `list2` (both of type int)

Now I want to remove content of `list2` from `list1`. How I can do this in C#?

PS: Don't use loop.

Comment: If `list1` contains `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5`, and `list2` contains `2, 3, 4`, what should the result be? `1, 5`, or `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`?

Comment: Also, the restriction "don't use loop" is silly. Any builtin method that does this will use some sort of loop.

Comment: @millimoose It's probably some kind of assignment - there'll be a clause stating that the student can't use a loop.

Comment: @Arry, please note that all provided solutions will be use loops but implicitly.

Comment: @Jeff Near as I can tell, there's no straightforward way to do anything except a "set difference" (which might or might not be correct) without a loop.

Comment: @millimoose If it's not a set difference that's required something like `var list3 = new List(list2); list1.RemoveAll(x => list3.Contains(x); list3.Remove(x));` (not sure about syntax there...) would do the job

Comment: @Jeff `Remove()` returns a `bool`, so just: `list1.RemoveAll(x=>list3.Remove(x))`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**IMPORTANT CHANGE**

As was pointed out in the comments, `.Except()` uses a set internally, so any duplicate members of `list1` will be absent in the final result.

> Produces the **set** difference of two sequences

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx

However, there is a solution that is both O(N) and preserves duplicates in the original list: Modify the `RemoveAll(i => list2.Contains(i))` approach to use a `HashSet<int>` to hold the exclusion set.

```
List<int> list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).ToList();
HashSet<int> exclusionSet = Enumerable.Range(500000, 10).ToHashSet(); 

list1.Remove(i => exclusionSet.Contains(i));
```

The extension method `ToHashSet()` is available in [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can use Linq

```
list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

Out of curiosity I did a simple benchmark of my solution vs. @HighCore's.

For `list2` having just one element, his code is faster.  As `list2` gets larger and larger, his code gets *extremely* slow.  It looks like his is **O(N-squared)** (or more specifically O(list1.length*list2.length) since each item in `list1` is compared to each item in `list2`).  Don't have enough data points to check the Big-O of my solution, but it is much faster when `list2` has more than a handful of elements.

Code used to test:

```
        List<int> list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).ToList();
        List<int> list2 = Enumerable.Range(500000, 10).ToList(); // Gets MUCH slower as 10 increases to 100 or 1000

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        //list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
        list1.RemoveAll(i => list2.Contains(i));

        sw.Stop();

        var ms1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

**UPDATE 2**

This solution assigns a new list to the variable `list1`.  As @Толя points out, other references (if any) to the original `list1` will not be updated.  This solution drastically outperforms `RemoveAll` for all but the smallest sizes of `list2`.  If no other references must see the update, it is preferable for that reason.

Comment: This does not actually remove any content from list1.

Comment: This is returns new list, and not removes from original.

Comment: Yeah, if there are any other references to the original list they will be unchanged, which means this is a circumstantial fix.

Comment: @Толя: Agreed.  However, it performs *much* better than `RemoveAll`.  The best solution depends on whether additional references must see the change (and I would argue code program with such side effects is not desirable).

Comment: @EricJ. That's fair. Out of interest, what's `n` in your `n-squared`? Is it the number of items in `list2` or is it the total number of items (so it's actually `O(list1.length*list2.length)`)?

Comment: @Jeff: The number of items in both lists I think.  Each item in `list1` is compared to each item in `list2`, so you are correct.  I'll update my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Oh, also: since this uses Sets internally, this will also nuke any duplicate values in `list1` regardless of whether they're in `list2`. That is, `new[]{1, 1, 2, 3}.Except(new[]{2, 3})` will result in `new[]{1}`. This seems less likely to be desirable behaviour.

Comment: @millimoose: You are correct.  I provided a new solution that is O(N) and does not remove duplicate elements from the list.

Comment: @EricJ.: "does not remove duplicate elements from the list" – [Yes it does.](http://ideone.com/21sTrU) Using `.Remove()` instead of `.Contains()` will also be wrong with a set. (Also, the method that takes a predicate is `List<>.RemoveAll()`.) You'd have to use a multi-set, but the BCL does not contain such a data structure; or, I suppose, a `T => int` dictionary that keeps track of the count of items. At which point I'd start asking how much I care about performance to avoid just doing `list1.RemoveAll(it=>list2Copy.Remove(it));`.

Comment: @millimoose: No, it doesn't.  `List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2 }; HashSet<int> excl = new HashSet<int>() { 2 };          list1.RemoveAll(p => excl.Contains(p));` leaves {1, 1} in `list1`.  Run it and see.

Comment: @EricJ. – My point is, if you use `excl = new HashSet<int> {1}`, you'll get the result `[2]`, **not** `[1, 2]`.

Comment: @millimoose: Yes.  That's my interpretation of the intended behavior.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: I've reread the comments and noticed my previous example was the other way around. (I.e. duplicates in the original are removed, as opposed to all – not one – occurences of an excluded item being removed.) Anyway, I did mean both, that is, ideally the method would do a *list difference* – remove each item from `list2` once from `list1, not any set-ish operation. (Still, the OP didn't specify, so it doesn't affect the validity of your interpretation.)

Answer (score 9):

```
list1.RemoveAll(x => list2.Contains(x));
```

Comment: +1 because this actually removes items from the original list. (That said it will remove all occurences of any element in `list2` from `list1` even if they repeat.)

Comment: @HighCore: My measurements show that this solution is much slower than mine if `list2` has more than a few elements.  I'm not surprised that this is O(n-squared) but am not sure why mine is much faster.

Comment: @EricJ. `.Except()` uses `Set`s internally, so the removal and such are O(n)

Comment: @millimoose: I actually measured times close to O(m*n).  See the code I ran in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
List<T> result = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove every item in the `secondList` from the `firstList`:

```
firstList.RemoveAll( item => { secondList.Contains(item); } );
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as HighCore's answer, but malformed (you're missing `);` at the end)