# Unique values of old list

Tags: c#, linq, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove sublist from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388834/remove-sublist-from-a-list)

I have 2 lists:

```
var oldList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};

var newList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,6,7};
```

How can i have the unique values of the oldlist (with LINQ)?

```
//hardcoded list:
var list =  new List<int>(){4,5};

//LINQ:
var list = ??
```

Comment: What should the result be if `oldList` is `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}`; and `newList` is `{1, 2, 3}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var unique = oldList.Except(newList);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = oldList.Except(newList).ToList();
```

It means that it will return all elements in `oldList` that are not in `newList`.

Answer (score 2):

You mean values in oldList that aren't in newList? If so:

```
var list = oldList.Except(newList);
```

See [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) on MSDN.

Add a call to `ToList()` if you genuinely need a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) method.

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

```
var oldList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var newList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 };

var value = oldList.Except(newList);

foreach (var i in value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/4bfoBC).

Answer (score 0):

You have to `Except` method.

```
var list = oldList.Except(newList);
```

> Produces the set difference of two sequences. [[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356791.aspx)]